# Alarm clock countdown timer java with user input for times

Tags: java, html, function, countdown, alarm

I want to create an application using html and java but I am having a little difficulty. The idea is to let the user input the date and time into a text box or date picker and click a butTon which will then countdownto that time and sound an alarm. I have a countdown working o a time that is put into the script however this is not user defined. My main problem is grabbing the info from the date picker to change the date in the script so the countdown will begin when the user clicks the button.

My technical skils are not great but I have a good idea of basic html and java

the follwing is the code i have

```
     <html>
<head>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
var eventdate = new Date("("month") 25, 2012 23:59:59");

function toSt(n) {
s=""
if(n<10) s+="0"
return s+n.toString();
}

function countdown() {
cl=document.clock;
d=new Date();
count=Math.floor((eventdate.getTime()-d.getTime())/1000);
if(count<=0)
{cl.days.value ="----";
cl.hours.value="--";
cl.mins.value="--";
cl.secs.value="--";
return;
}
cl.secs.value=toSt(count%60);
count=Math.floor(count/60);
cl.mins.value=toSt(count%60);
count=Math.floor(count/60);
cl.hours.value=toSt(count%24);
count=Math.floor(count/24);
cl.days.value=count; 

setTimeout("countdown()",500);
}




  function date() {

  var monthentered = document.getElementById('month').value;

  var dayentered = document.getElementById('day').value;

  var yearentered = document.getElementById('year').value;



  }




</SCRIPT>


</head>

<body>

<input type="button" name="button" value="press me" onclick="date()"/>

<p> insert month <input type="text" id="month"  size="15"> </p>
<p> insert day <input type="text" id="day" size="15"> </p>
<p> insert year <input type="text" id="year" size"15"> </p>


<input

<FORM name="clock">
<TABLE BORDER=5 CELLSPACING=5 CELLPADDING=0 BGCOLOR="#000000">
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER WIDTH="31%" BGCOLOR="#000080"><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF"><B>Days:</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER WIDTH="23%" BGCOLOR="#000080"><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF"><B>Hours:</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER WIDTH="23%" BGCOLOR="#000080"><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF"><B>Mins:</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER WIDTH="23%" BGCOLOR="#000080"><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF"><B>Secs:</B></FONT></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER><INPUT name="days" size=4></TD>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER><INPUT name="hours" size=2></TD>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER><INPUT name="mins" size=2></TD>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER><INPUT name="secs" size=2></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD COLSPAN="4" BGCOLOR="#000080">
<CENTER><P><FONT FACE="arial,helvetica" SIZE="+2" COLOR="#FFFF00">Until</FONT></CENTER>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD COLSPAN="4" BGCOLOR="#000000">
<CENTER><P><FONT COLOR="#00FF00" SIZE=+1>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
document.write(" " + eventdate.toLocaleString() + " ");
// end hiding script-->
</SCRIPT>
</FONT>
</CENTER>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</FORM>


</body>




</html>
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code? Would help to answer your question.

Comment: What do you have so far. BTW you don't need java, but javascript. Just make a onclick method on your button. An in the onclick method, fetch the value from your date/time input field.

Answer (score 0):

If you use javascript and not java wouldn't that be better?

You could use document.getElementById('id') to grab bits from form if you wanted?

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function doIT(){
         var picked_date = document.getElementById('date_box').value;
         var picked_time = document.getElementById('time_box').value;
         // now your stuff here



         alert('Date: ' + picked_date + ' Time: ' +picked_time);

   }


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
   <!-- this is my form type thang -->
   <label>Date:</label><input type="text" id="date_box" size="8" value=""/>           
   <label>Time:</label><input type="text" id="time_box" size="8" value=""/>
   <input type="button" name="button" value="Press Me" onclick="doIT()"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One thing I will say given your brief is that with the date picking and expecting it to work require using cookies and the user coming back to your page the very moment your alarm is about to go off otherwise it wont work as expected. If you use Java and build an actual application then you need to look at services and running/installing them in the background whatever platform you are on/expect your users to be on

Comment: this is perfect its something simple in Javascript would be what I am looking for. I have the following code and I think I have grabbed the info from the input boxes in tis code now all I would need to do is get the date to update in the timer when I hit a button, I have no clue how to put the date the user entered into the script which the timer is counting down to.

Answer (score 0):

Given your skill set as you describe I suggest you to use javascript( jquery + [countdown](http://www.keith-wood.name/countdown.html) plugin)